# Wordpress Invisible Pages

Tags: wordpress

I'd worked with some pages and moved them to Trash. When I wanted to revisit them, even though it says Trash(2) and I believe there should be 2 pages, this folder looks empty and I couldn't find them.

[image]

Where have they gone?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is the memory issue. Please put these lines in the `wp-config.php` file.

```
/** Memory Limit */
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define( 'WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M' );
```

and to enable `WP_DEBUG`, open your `wp-config.php` file and look for

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

**Note:** In this case, the errors will be saved to a `debug.log log file` inside the `/wp-content/` directory.

and change it to

```
 define('WP_DEBUG', true);
 define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```